# First few energy Levels in Iridium?

Tags: atomic-physics

I've been learning a bit of x-ray spectra on the side. I know that Iridium has Z = 77, and I am trying to plot out the first 4 energy levels.

I learnt that electrons are filled up as $1s^2,2s^2,2p^6,3s^2,3p^6, 4s^2, 3d^{10}$.

I looked up the energy levels of Iridium and found that the most tightly bound energy levels have ionization energies $76.1, 13.4, 12.8, 11.2 ~keV$. Are the first 4 energy levels simply $n=1,n=2,n=3,n=4$? If so, then are they simply $1s^2,2s^2,3s^2,4s^2$?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you quote are the [X-ray fluorescence lines, i.e. the K, L, M and N lines](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_1.html), not the energies of the electrons in an iridium atom.

For example the first energy, 76.1 keV, is the $K_\alpha$ line and corresponds to the energy change when an electron falls from the $2s$ level into the $1s$ level. That is, the X-rays eject an electron from the $1s$ orbital then an electron from the $2s$ orbital falls into the $1s$ orbital and emits a photon corresponding to the energy difference. Likewise the second energy, 13.4 keV, is the energy change when a $2s$ electron is ejected and an electron falls from the $3s$ into the $2s$ orbital.

So the energies of the X-ray lines give the **differences** in the energies of the orbitals, not the energies themselves. Actually it's more complicated than that, because the energies of the orbitals change when the iridium atom is ionised. So the $K_\alpha$ energy is the energy difference between the $2s$ orbital in a neutral iridium atom and the $1s$ orbital in an Ir$^+$ ion.

So there isn't any simple relationship between the X-ray energies you cite and the energy of the atomic orbitals in Iridium. I don't know any easy way to experimentally measure the energies of the atomic orbitals in multi-electron atoms, but they can be calculated using quantum mechanics. For example the energies of the $s$ levels is given by:

$$ E_n = 13.6 \frac{Z_{eff}^2}{n^2} $$

where $Z_{eff}$ is the effective nuclear charge calculated using quantum mechanics. You can find the [values of the effective nuclear charges tabulated](http://www.webelements.com/iridium/atoms.html).

The order of the atomic orbital energies is given by the [Madelung rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle#Madelung_energy_ordering_rule) (with a few exceptions). So the order of the first four levels in iridium is $1s$, $2s$, $2p$, $3s$.